# Return multiple primary keys of inserted datatable using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have inserted multiple records as a datatable in SQL Server through my c# code. For this purpose I created a user defined table type and then a stored procedure to insert all the records of the datatable using one insert. Now my problem is, I need to get the ids (primary key column values) for these newly inserted multiple records. Is there a way like the OUTPUT inserted.primarykey where I can get multiple primary keys?

Comment: you can use `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve the primary key and you also need to add `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after your insert statement. i.e if your primary key is an **IDENTITY** column

Comment: Thanks! let me try doing this.

Comment: you could use output inserted on your stored procedure.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/output-clause.aspx

Comment: you're most welcome @Swati. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

yes you will need to use a table variable with output clause something like this....

```
DECLARE @NewIds TABLE(ID INT)

INSERT INTO TableName (Col1 , Col2, Col3)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @NewIds(ID)
VALUES (  1 , 1 , 1)
      ,(  2 , 1 , 1)
      ,(  3 , 1 , 1)

-- now select from the table variable to see the newly inserted ids 

SELECT * FROM @NewIds
```